# React.js: Access Overall App State from a Standalone Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Component that is not owned by any other Component. The page will jump to it when a user clicks a link, which is implemented with react-router.

```
<Link to={`/weather-stations/${this.props.active_device}`} >view detail
</Link>
```

And I cannot find a way to pass the state of the app to that Component, like: `<ComponentName data={ this.state }/>` I wonder what is the recommended way to do this in React? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe using contexts? http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

Answer (score 1):

The "official" (i.e. used by Facebook) way of doing this is via the Flux architecture as described here: https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html

Essentially, this involves the creation of "Stores" which hold the data which is then accessed and displayed by your React components. In your example, you might create a `WeatherStationDataStore`, keyed on the `active_device` ID - the component at the other end of that link can pick up the ID from the URL and dispatch an "Action" that calls `WeatherStationDataStore.get(id)` - if there's any server interaction needed to get the data it can be abstracted via the store.

The standard "to do list" example for Flux can be found here: https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html and is a good introduction to the concepts.

Comment: Flux is a fine solution, and the one used by Facebook, but I'm not sure I'd say it's the "official" answer. A more generic solution will involve *any* sort of global application state that lives *outside* of the application (like flux stores do).

Comment: Fair point @MichelleTilley, I didn't mean to imply the "only" solution: You could of course have, say, a singleton data store object that's called directly, not worrying about the dispatcher and actions etc. and that's something I've implemented with React in the past. We ended up moving on to a "proper" Flux implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

In linking component -

```
<Link to={`/weather-stations/${this.props.active_device}`} state={{"foo":"bar"}} >view detail
</Link>
```

And in the linked Component

```
var data = this.props.location.state;
//doSomethingWithData(data.foo);
```